# Should I use sprang or sprung in this case?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

She..... to her feet when she knew the right answer.

A) Spring
B) Sprung
C) Sprang

Comment: When out on the lawn there arose such a clatter,
I sprang from my bed to see what was the matter.
Away to the window I flew like a flash,
Tore open the shutters and threw up the sash.  And spring had sprung.

Comment: Replace "spring" with "go" or "eat", then ask yourself the same question.

Answer (score 1):

She ***sprang*** to her feet. See this [full conjugation](https://www.wordreference.com/conj/EnVerbs.aspx?v=spring) of the verb *spring*.
I wonder what made you think otherwise!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. It's very useful to visit the site's Help Center to read about the standards the site sets for good answers. For example, it's customary to link to credible sources for information that is not opinion-based.

Comment: And 'I wonder what made you think otherwise!' means that you consider this question rather basic; you also rapidly provide an answer from an easily accessible source. The answering of such questions only encourages further questions not suitable for ELU.